# ajax like button

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do i use ajax to make my like button functional.

```
<form>
<input type='submit' id='like>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { id: "xyz" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```